# how much width and height image for android tablet?

Tags: android, image, height, width, tablet

i have display image in android tablet..

real size is 209x209 px, it's actualy big..
but when i display it in android tablet, it's become small..

how much standart width and height for image in android tablet?

Comment: please elaborate your question ... Specify what you want to do ? we don't understand your question

Answer (score 2):

The available width and height of Tab in market are following:

Product            Display Size     Display Resolution  Aspect Ratio
Motorola XOOM           10.1"               1280 x 800              16:9

Samsung Galaxy Tab       7"                 1024 x 600              16:9

Cruz T301            7"                  800 x 600               4:3

Coby Kyros MID7005       7"                  800 x 480               5:3

Dell Streak              5"                  800 x 480               5:3

Archos 43           4.3"                 854 x 480              16:9

So no standard width and height for images for tab in Android.

You can only think about that which size is suitable for those.

You can use 520*340 for 1280*800

500*320 for 1224*600

420*320 for 800*600

Answer (score 0):

## What are the most common screen resolutions: Android phones

320 x 480

480 x 800

480 x 854

540 x 960

1280 x 720

1920 x 1080

## What are the most common screen resolutions?: Android tablets

1024 x 600

1280 x 800

1920 x 1080

2048 x 1536

2560 x 1440

2560 x 1600

found list of screen res via [gravitylab](http://www.gravlab.com/2013/11/21/common-android-screen-resolutions-video/)